# Criação de dicionário com vários valores pra uma chave

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um código para cadastro por `input`, como exercício.

```
dic = {}
    ...
def cadastrar():
   nome = input('Nome: ')
   variavel1 = input('variavel 1,: ')
   variavel2 = input('Variavel 2: ')
   dic.update({'nome': 'variavel1', 'variavel2'})

while True:
    opcao = exibirMenu()
    if opcao == ('cadastrar'):
        cadastrar()
```

esse código da erro de sintaxe, mudo o código para:

```
dic.update('nome', 'varriavel1', 'variavel2')
```

e retorna o erro

> TypeError: update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

como faço para salvar os dados em conjunto, `nome = variavel1, variavel2`. para que possa acessar o nome e retornar as variáveis anexadas ao nome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode cadastrar uma tupla. Para criar uma tupla, as duas variáveis devem estar envolvidas por parênteses:

```
dic.update({'nome': (variavel1, variavel2)})
```

Também é importante lembrar que quando se faz uma referencia a uma variável, não se usa aspas. `'variavel1'` é uma constante de string cujo valor é `'variavel1'`, e não o valor que realmente está na variável `'variavel1'`.

Para acessar os valores da tupla em seu dicionário, você faria assim:

```
print(dic['nome'][0])  # variavel1
print(dic['nome'][1])  # variavel2
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado, amigo. só mais uma dúvida:
teria como mudar o formato dos dados ao serem retornados por print?
ele retorna assim: {'nome': ('variavel1', 'variavel2', 'nome2': ('variavel3', 'variavel 4')})
queria dar uma melhorada estética, para ficar assim: Nome: variavel1, variavel2. Nome2: variavel3, variavel4.

ou seria melhor criar um banco de dados no mysql?

Comment: @bryan você pode criar uma função pra mostrar os dados do jeito que quiser. Quando você usa print num dicionário, ele sai de uma forma padronizada pra que você possa saber qual é o tipo de estrutura que está dentro dele (por exemplo, uma lista usa colchetes e uma tupla usa parênteses). Um banco de dados no mysql é um caso de uso bem diferente de um dicionário, e vai depender da sua necessidade. Nesse caso, não parece ser necessário.

Comment: ok, pedro. entendi. com tua ajuda consegui passar dessa parte que estava com muita dificuldade, estou tentando passar de uma dificuldade agora nas funções while e else. nessa minha ultima mensagem acho que misturei um pouco minhas dúvidas kkk. seria se era possível editar o jeito de mostrar os dados e se era melhor salvar os dados de entrada em um banco de dados para serem acessados e editados depois. ex: usuários cadastram item com variáveis de cor e peso e outros usuários podem acessar uma lista com itens de todos os usuários.
se der, da uma olhada no código https://pastebin.com/kWmHBT9C